# How do I store bash env vars in array then access/modify?

Tags: bash, environment-variables, array

I want to store environment variables in a bash array, and then use them in cases where I perform the same operation on all of them (unset, export an so on).  For example, if I want to print all env vars in my array:

```
envVar1="firstVar"
envVar2="secondVar"
envVar3="thirdVar"
envVars=(envVar1 envVar2 envVar3)
for currentEnvVar in "${envVars[@]}" 
do
    # print env var name and value
    printf "Initial Value: %s = %s\n" "${currentEnvVar}" "${currentEnvVar}"
    # unset env var
    printf "Unsetting %s\n" "${currentEnvVar}"
    unset "${currentEnvVar}"

    # print env var name and value
    printf "Unset Variable (nothing should be to right of '=') %s = %s\n\n" "${currentEnvVar}" "${currentEnvVar}"

    # set env var 
    printf "Setting %s\n" "${currentEnvVar}"
    export "${currentEnvVar}"="${currentEnvVar}""_new"

    # print env var name and new value...
    printf "New Value %s =  %s\n\n" "${currentEnvVar}" "${currentEnvVar}"

done
```

What I am unsure of is how to store the variables in `envVars` and how to use them in the loop.

My goal is for the output of the above loop to be:

```
Initial Value: envVar1 = firstVar
Unsetting envVar1
Unset Variable (nothing should be to right of '=') envVar1 =

Setting envVar1
New Value envVar1 =  firstVar_new

Initial Value: envVar2 = secondVar
Unsetting envVar2
Unset Variable (nothing should be to right of '=') envVar2 =

Setting envVar2
New Value envVar2 =  secondVar_new

Initial Value: envVar3 = thirdVar
Unsetting envVar3
Unset Variable (nothing should be to right of '=') envVar3 =

Setting envVar3
New Value envVar3 = thirdVar_new
```

But what I get is this:

```
Initial Value: envVar1 = envVar1
Unsetting envVar1
Unset Variable (nothing should be to right of '=') envVar1 = envVar1

Setting envVar1
New Value envVar1 =  envVar1

Initial Value: envVar2 = envVar2
Unsetting envVar2
Unset Variable (nothing should be to right of '=') envVar2 = envVar2

Setting envVar2
New Value envVar2 =  envVar2

Initial Value: envVar3 = envVar3
Unsetting envVar3
Unset Variable (nothing should be to right of '=') envVar3 = envVar3

Setting envVar3
New Value envVar3 =  envVar3
```

Is this even possible?  How do I set up the array of environment variable names then use, or modify, their values?

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of different pieces to what you seem to be trying to do.

To `unset` a variable whose name is in another variable, you can use `-v` so

```
unset -v "$currentEnvVar"
```

for that part.  See [here](http://www.unix.com/man-page/posix/1posix/unset/)

To assign to a variable you can use [`printf`](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/printf) like

```
printf -v "$currentEnvVar" %s 'new value'
```

To print the value you can use an [indirect reference](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006]) like

```
printf 'The value is %s\n' "${!currentEnvVar}"
```

In brace expansion if the first character is `!` the rest is treated as the name of a variable that contains the name of the variable you want to actually use.

You could also consider using an [associative array](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arrays.html) instead, if it suits your needs:

```
declare -A envVarsByName
envVarsByName[$currentEnvVar]='new value'
printf 'New val: %s\n' "${envVarsByName[$currentEnvVar]]}"
```